# Find basis for orthogonal complement polynomial

Tags: inner-products

Consider the complex vector space of complex polynomials of degree at most $2$, with standard inner product $$\langle p,q \rangle = \int_{0}^1 p(x)\overline{q(x)} dx.$$

How would you find a basis for the orthogonal complement of $J$ where $J=Span(ix^2)$?

EDIT: Using Gram-Schmidt

Comment: I think [Gram Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) is one approach.

Comment: What do I do with the $ix$?

Comment: $ix^2$ is a vector, so start with $ix^2$ and then try some other things, like $1$ or $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomials $x \mapsto 1$, $x \mapsto x$, $x \mapsto ix^2$ form a basis for the space. Now apply Gram Schmidt, but start with the $x \mapsto ix^2$ vector.

Then the other two will be orthogonal to this and hence span the orthogonal complement.
$f_0(x) = ix^2$

$g_0(x) = \sqrt{5}ix^2$ (after normalising).

$f_1(x) = 1 - \langle g_0, x \mapsto 1\rangle g_0(x) = 1-{5 \over3} x^2$,

$g_1(x)= {3 \over 2} - {5 \over 2} x^2$.

$f_2(x) = x - \langle g_0, x \mapsto x \rangle g_0(x) - \langle g_1, x \mapsto x \rangle g_1(x) = {1 \over 16} (-3+16x-15x^2)$,

$g_2(x) = {\sqrt{3} \over 2 } (-3+16x-15x^2)$.

It is easy (but tedious) to check that $g_0,g_1,g_2$ are orthonormal, hence
$J^\bot = \operatorname{sp} \{ g_1,g_2 \}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $x \mapsto 1$?

Comment: The notation $x\mapsto f(x)$ means the function $f$ (as opposed to its value at a single point $x$).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all polynomials of the form $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ such that

$$
\langle p, ix^2\rangle = -i\int_0^1 x^2(ax^2 + bx + c)\,dx = 0
$$

Therefore you need $a/5 + b/4 + c/3 = 0 \iff c = -3a/5 - 3b/4$. It follows that

$$
p(x) = a(x^2 - 3/5) + b(x - 3/4)
$$

Hence the orthogonal complement is given by

$$
J^\perp = \operatorname*{span}\{x - 3/4, x^2 - 3/5\}
$$

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the part about using the Gram--Schmidt procedure until after writing my solution.

Comment: That's okay! Thanks for helping :) so how come the integral in your solution equals zero?

Comment: The orthogonal complement of $J$ is the set of all polynomials $J^\perp$ that are orthogonal to $J$ with respect to the standard inner product. Thus $\langle p,q\rangle = 0$ for all $p\in J^\perp$ and all $q\in J$.

Comment: Okay thanks! I tried using Gram-Schmidt (http://m.imgur.com/tvybWZc) but I don't think it worked. Can you see where I went wrong?